# this support library should not use a different version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

I've seen a lot of people having a similar problem and the solution was a change of version on either the `compileSdkVersion` or the Support Libraty Version.
Here my problem is that I do have the same compileSdkVersion and the same Support Library Version but the error still shows.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.4.0'
}

dependencies {

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

The error:

`This support library should not use a different version(24) than the compileVersionSDK(23)`

The error began to show right after I updated to Android Studio 2.2

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: Try removing `support-v4` and `appcompat-v7`

Comment: Support library is still higher then buildtoolsversion could this be a problem?

Comment: I just edited. Sorry about it

Comment: @namlik I tried changing the `buildToolsVersion` to 23.4.0 and Android Studio says: "All packages are not available for download!  The following packages are not available:
- Package id build-tools;23.4.0"

Comment: @cricket_007 Removing them didn't work.

Comment: `23.0.3` is the latest build tools. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Comment: Dangit mb i thought they would update buildtools together with the supportversion mb ill have a look around if i can find anything

Comment: Can you give supportlibversion 23.0.0 a go? And tell me how that goes?

Comment: @cricket_007 Changed the `buildToolsVersion` to `23.0.3` and the problem persists.

Comment: @namlik Didn't work. I'm rebuilding the project. I'm also starting to think that the problem must be somewhere else, this makes no sense. This happened after I updated to Android Studio 2.2 (adding this to the question)

Comment: Yea it seems so cause supplibs 23.0.0 should definatly work you can tey and lower it a bit more but other then i havent got a clue

Comment: Ok. I think I got it but I don't understand why. If I change `${supportLibVersion}`  to `23.4.0` and with the single ' the problem won't show, only the warning that I should use 24.2.1 instead. Which rises the question: What's wrong with `ext { supportLibVersion = '23.0.0' }` ?

Comment: I use the `ext` section with `23+`, but use IntelliJ instead of Android Studio. I haven't seen this error before